# How do you get Javascript to see tinyint(1) data pulled via AJAX request as boolean?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, boolean

I am having a problem and after hours of searching for answers and playing around with it I cannot get it to work.

My problem. I have a MYSQL database. When I pull my "boolean" data from the database via PHP it is just fine. PHP interprets the "strings" of 1's and 0's as True and False. However, when I retrieve this data to populate a form with Ajax I run into a problem.

The string comes out as: {"id":"478","name":"aaaa","manager":"385","usertype":"0","typeone":"0","typetwo":"1","typethree":"1"}

That is just fine. Until I try to populate a form with the data using:

```
$.each(data, function (name, val) {
var $el = $('[id="e' + name + '"]'),
    type = $el.attr('type');

switch (type) {
    case 'checkbox':
        $el.filter('[value="' + Boolean(val) + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
        break;
    case 'radio':
        $el.filter('[value="' + val + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
        break;
    default:
        $el.val(val);
}
});
```

On this http://jsfiddle.net/z66XF/11/ you can see that data used to check off the check boxes doesn't work when it comes from my database with the "boolean" values given as strings.

"0" ends up being evaluated as true.

Is there any way to convert this or have javascript see it as boolean?

Comment: Look at how you are generating your JSON server-side. You want `"usertype":0` and not `"usertype":"0"`. Then JavaScript will just work. If the value in your PHP array is an int `0` and not a string, PHP will JSON encode it as an int, and it will all just work.

Comment: Strings are "true" in JS if they are not empty, otherwise false.  http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Comment: From what I have read it is MYSQL that is spitting out the values as strings and, also from what I've read, we are just supposed to be OK with that because PHP handles them correctly. But when you try passing it to Javascript it isn't handled correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Unary Plus Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29) to convert the string to a number

```
Boolean(+val)
```

Basic Example:

```
var one = "1";
var zero = "0";

console.log("one", one, Boolean(+one));  //one "1" true
console.log("zero", zero, Boolean(+zero));  //zero 0 false
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JJRP3/

Comment: Like `0 + val`? Well I never.

Comment: Not like `0 + val`, more like `-val`, except with +

Comment: This works in the jsfiddle, but not on my actual website. Everything is copied word for word and nadda. I am going to recreate the jsfiddle in its own file and see if that does anything good.

Comment: I was missing `value="true"` in my form.